# Android music player plays two songs sametime

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am trying to make a music player on `android`. I have found the songs and list them on a `listview`. After I choose the song from the `listview`, it starts to play, also if I quit the app it's keep playing. But when I turn to app and select another song, the last song that I have chosen keeps playing, Actually here the song which I recent selected should starts to play, so two songs play same time. How can I prevent it? I play the songs with the code below

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(player != null){
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
            uri=Uri.parse(fileList.get(position).toString());
            player=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
            player.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's not what i ask. If i don't send the the app to the background there is no problem but when i quit and turn back to the app and click another list item i want to stop the music that playing and starts the music that i select but it doesn't work like that i mean if i quit and open the app again the code that check the music player null or not null see the player is null but it playing a song so it can't be null http://stackoverflow.com/users/991479/ewald

Answer (score -1):

***Make Mediaplayer class as singleton*** ,as media player classes creates multipe instatnces

Comment: Can you give me more details